# How to Negate a Context

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, negate

I want to select elements, but not if one of their ancestor matches a certain selector.

For example, let's say I want to match all `<a>` nodes that are not descendants of a table.

I tried something like this:

```
$("a", ":not(table *)");
```

but that crashes my browser.

This one also hangs my browser:

```
jQuery("a", ":not(table td)");
```

The page queried is quite large, with lots of very large tables. So, I need something that performs well too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers are over-complicating things.

```
$('a').not('table a');
```

-or-

```
$('a:not(table a)');
```

The second parameter in the `jQuery` function is the context under which to search for an element, but selecting `:not(table)` will select *every* element that is not a table, which includes descendants of tables. Usually you want to use the context parameter when you have a specific document or element under which you would like to search.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, performance is worse when not scanning the tables, I guess because the :not selector takes some time as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').not(function() {
   return $(this).closest('table').length > 0;
});
```

or will likely be faster if they are always direct children of a `<td>` tag

```
$('a').not(function() {
   return $(this).parent('td').length > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("a").not("td a")
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/cPqdf/).